# The Facebook Birthday Problem（Birthday Problem Variation）

Tags: probability, expected-value, random, coupon-collector, birthday

The Facebook Birthday Problem:

This problem stems from the classic Birthday Paradox.
It says:

> How many friends do you need for the probability of having at least one friend with a birthday each day to be greater than 50%?
> Answer: If there are 23 friends, the probability of two or more people sharing a birthday exceeds 50%. If there are 60 people, the probability exceeds 99%.

If there are birthdays every day among my friends on Facebook, and I want to send birthday wishes to them every day, how many friends do I need to achieve this daily occurrence? How is the probability calculated?

Q1-1: If I have 1000 friends on Facebook, what is the probability that there will be a friend's birthday every day?
Q1-2: If I have 5000 friends on Facebook, what is the probability that there will be a friend's birthday every day?

Q2-1: How many friends do I need at least to ensure that there is a friend's birthday every day with a probability of more than 50%?
Q2-2: How many friends do I need at least to ensure that there is a friend's birthday every day with a probability of more than 99%?

(Calculations are made without considering leap years.)

This problem is not really a "Birthday Problem", but more like a "coupon collector's problem".

Comment: Your statement of the birthday paradox is incorrect.  The question isn't "How many friends do you need for the probability of having at least one friend with a birthday each day to be greater than 50%?"  It is "How many friends do you need for the probability that at least two of them share a birthday to be at least 50%"  These are completely different questions.  Your question there is more akin to the coupon collector problem.

Comment: Thank you for your correction, I give it a note. @Aaron

Comment: @Aaron the OP *did* say it *stems* from the Birthday paradox.  So I assumed the question indeed was as asked.  What's weird though is the quoted "it" (whatever it is) states Question: the new question but Answer: the old birthday with no change whatsoever even to the point of referring "the class" (what class?  who said anything about a class?)

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, correct the description again. @fleablood

Comment: Well, the probability of having a friend with a birthday on Jan. 1st if $1-\frac {364}{365}^{1000}$.  The probability of having a friend with a birthday on the Jan. 1st and on Jan. 1st ought to be $(1-\frac{364}{365}^{1000}) \times (1-\frac{364}{365}^{999})$.  But my intuition says I'm probably overcounting ("what if a picked friend A for the birthday of Jan. 1 but didn't consider friend B as well") but I don't see immediately that I am.  I'd say the probability of a friend's birthday every day is $\prod_{i=0}^{364} (1-\frac {365}{365})^{1000-k}$

Comment: "Sorry for the confusion, correct the description again."  Don't feel obligated to edit for *every* comment!  What on *earth* about my comment made feel you had to edit anyway?  But, sheesh, did you ever hear the fable about the father the son and the donkey?  The change who is and isn't riding the donkey in response to *every* comment they hear "The mean old man making his tiny son walk" "that lazy son making the old man walk" "the mean people overburdening the poor donkey" "those idiots both walking when they have a perfectly good donkey".  The end up carry the donkey on poles.

Comment: My point wasn’t whether or not the new problem is like the birthday paradox, my point was that you say “the classical birthday paradox is this” and then give the wrong statement for what the classical birthday paradox problem is (but then right answer to the classical problem). You don’t have to mention the coupon collector problem, you should avoid problems like this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have $n$ friends, the probability that you have a friend with each birthday is
$$
\frac{{n\brace 365}\cdot 365!}{365^n}.
$$
The notation ${n\brace k}$ refers to the Stirling numbers of second kind, which can be calculated using this formula:
$$
{n\brace k}=\frac1{k!}\sum_{j=0}^k(-1)^{j}\binom kj(k-j)^n.
$$
Plugging in $1000$ and $5000$ for $n$ into that formula answers your first two questions. For $1000$ friends, the probability is nearly zero (one in a trillion), while for $5000$ friends, the probability is $\approx 99.96\%$.  You can then use a computer to find the smallest value of $n$ for which that formula is greater than $0.5$ and $0.99$. Doing so, I found that you need $2287$ friends to succeed more than $50\%$ of the time, and you need $3828$ friends to succeed more than $99\%$ of the time.

Answer (score 1):

When you have $n$ friends on Facebook, the probability that there is a friend's birthday every day is given by

$$P_n=\mathbb P \left (\cap_{i=1}^{365} D'_i \right )=\\1-\mathbb P \left (\cup_{i=1}^{365} D_i \right )=\\1- \sum_{i=1}^{365} (-1)^{i-1}  \binom{365}{i} \left (1-\frac{i}{365} \right )^n=$$ $$\color{blue}{\sum_{i=0}^{365} (-1)^{i}  \binom{365}{i} \left (1-\frac{i}{365} \right )^n} \tag{1}$$

where $D_i$ is the event that there is no birthday in day $i$ (the inclusion-exclusion principle is applied to find the probability of the union $\cup_{i=1}^{365} D_i$).

Using (1), the answers to both parts of $Q1$ can be obtained by setting $n=1000$ and $n=5000$.

To solve Q2, you need to find the smallest $n$ that satisfies:

$$ P_n \ge \alpha$$

for $\alpha=0.5$ and $\alpha= 0.99$.

Working with the sum appearing in (1) seems difficult. Fortunately, using

$$ e^{-\frac{i}{365}} \approx 1-\frac{i}{365},$$

the formula (1) can be  well approximated by the following simple formula:

$$\color{blue}{P_n \approx \left (1-e^{-\frac{n}{365}} \right)^{365}}.$$

This **approximation** enables us to compute the probability $P_n$ easily. For $n=1000$ and $n=5000$, it returns $2.6 \times 10^{-11}$ and $0.9995898$, which are very close to the actual values.

Moreover, to have $P_n \ge \alpha$, we get the closed-form lower bound for $n$:

$$\color{blue}{n \ge -365 \log \left (1-\alpha^{\frac{1}{365}} \right)}.$$